# yii2:Custom Pagination for Gridview in form view

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2

I have included the Gridview widget in **`_form.php`** file, which is working well. The problem is the filter and pagination.

```
<?php
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => \app\models\ServiceCharges::find(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5,
    ],
]);

 ?>
    <?php  
   $searchModel = New \app\models\ServiceChargesSearch(); 
   $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

   ?>

        </div>
</div>
<div>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

           'id',
           'service_name',                
           'room_category',
           'charges_cash',
           'charges_cashless',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

    </div>
```

If I am putting the `$dataprovider` pagination part below the `$searchmodel`, pagination works fine, but then filter doesn't work and vice-versa.

How can I have both filter and pagination working in the _form.php.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have no experience with Yii2 but if it is similar than 1..

Why are you declaring `dataProvider` twice? I imagine the first one is to be able to customize page size.

So what happens is you use one data provider to set pagination but then you pass a different one to the table.

Second I don't know how your model looks inside but..

Since I can see the `search()` method returns a `dataProvider`, you should change the pagination inside there.

Or I think you can change it right after the `search()` method returns the `dataProvider` like:

```
$searchModel = New \app\models\ServiceChargesSearch(); 
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;
```

So you don't need the first instance of `dataProvider` that you've declared before.

As for the filters I do not know how it exactly behaves your `ServiceChargesSearch::search` function

But in Yii1 you normally:

> 1) Define model 2) Fill it up with data from `$_GET` 3) Pass
>   `$model->search()` to grid

If filters still not work you can provide code from the model.

Comment: Can we set pagination on views page in gridview::widget ?

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way in the controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new YourModels();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 10;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```