# Adjusting pagesize in Gridview Yii 2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I am trying to modify the `pagesize` of `GridView widget` in Yii 2 but I can't see any documents or reference that could help me.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
<?=
        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                'object_name',
                'name',
                'name_search',

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ],
        ]); 
?>
```

How can I limit the pageSize for example in 6 items only then it will show page numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pagination` in  DataProvider under `SearchModel`:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
  'pagination' =>
     [
      'pageSize' => 6
     ],
]);
```

**OR**

```
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327446/yii2custom-pagination-for-gridview-in-form-view)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but where is $query from? I got an undefined variable $query error.

Comment: I see. I am still having this error `Object of class yii\data\ActiveDataProvider could not be converted to string`

Comment: you have to add `'pagination' =>
     [
      'pageSize' => 6
     ], ` in searchModel not in view or index.

Comment: THANKS! Actually I already did this awhile ago but I only edited on the view part. Sorry I am having a hard time reading the documentation